# Strings and array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, string, structure

***UPDATED WITH NEW CODE
I'm trying to load a file data with an unknown amount of lines of data.
The data is organized as last, first:score1:score2:score3:score5:lettergrade

I'm getting the file to (sort of) load into an array and print.
When the data prints, it doesn't print the first name, just the first. It's printing the same integer for evert data element except for the last one, that comes out at 0 for all. Also, it's not flushing the data that doesn't return 8 elements.
PLEASE help!
Thanks in advance.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    #define FFLUSH while(fgetsc(fp) != '\n')
    #define MAX_STUDENTS 45

        typedef struct aStudent
        {
            char name[26];
            int id[7];
            int test1[4];
            int test2[4];
            int proj1[4];
            int proj2[4];
            int proj3[4];
            char grade[4];
        } aStudent;

        int main(void)
        {

        char file_name[FILENAME_MAX];
        FILE* fp;
        int i;
        int rc;
        int dc;
        aStudent studentArray[MAX_STUDENTS];

        printf("Enter File Name:    ");
        rc = scanf("%s", &file_name);
        if (rc == 0)
        {
            printf("\n\nError: No file name entered.");
            exit(0);
        }

        fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: Could not open file %s for read", file_name);
            exit(0);
        }

            for(int i=0; i< 45; i++)
            {

            dc = (fscanf(fp, "%s[^:]%d[^:]%d[^:]%d[^:]%d[^:]%d[^:]%d[^:]%f[^:]%c[^:\n]", studentArray[i].name, studentArray[i].id, studentArray[i].test1, studentArray[i].test2, studentArray[i].proj1, studentArray[i].proj2, studentArray[i].proj3, studentArray[i].grade));

            if (dc != 8)
            {
                FFLUSH;
            }

                printf("%s %d %d %d %d %d %d %.2f %c", studentArray[i].name, studentArray[i].id, studentArray[i].test1, studentArray[i].test2, studentArray[i].proj1, studentArray[i].proj2, studentArray[i].proj3, studentArray[i].grade);

        }

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "expected expression before token" errors.  OK.  Which. Line. Are.  The.  Errors. On.

Comment: The `FFLUSH` macro needs a semicolon at the end where you use it

Comment: my apologies, line 53. the line that simply has } under FFLUSH.

Comment: Not really. That macro needs to **die**. Get rid of it. Make a proper function.

Comment: thanks yano! i'm also getting a warning on line 48, saying my fgets passing argument from incompatible pointer type. my assignment seems correct to me?

Comment: even after adding a ; to the end of my FFLUSH, i'm still getting an error stating "expected expression before 'STUDENT'

Comment: that's due to the problem pointed out in the answer below. `STUDENT` is a type, you need a variable name. It's like you've declared `int[45];` And now are simply going around your code and saying `int[3] = x;`, `int[40] = y`. If you want to declare a variable immediately after the struct definition do something like `struct STUDENT{ ...} students[MAX_STUDENTS];` Now you'll have an array of `struct STUDENTS` that is `MAX_STUDENTS` long accessible from the `students` variable.

Comment: You have confused `fscanf` and `fgets` (e.g. `fgets(fp, "%s[^:]%d....`) There is no format string with `fgets` and the first parameter is a pointer to hold the line read.

Comment: okay, i've made adjustments and i also understand what i did wrong... I'm still getting this expected token error on my fflush... I don't see the error

Comment: its looking for a ) somewhere

Comment: yes, of course. my parenthesis are matching, thus why i'm so confused. BTW i updated the original question with the code i have now.

Comment: i really hope i'm not being silly and missing something so obvious... but at the end of that fscanf there are two consecutive )) to close the two (( in the begining of the fscanf.

Comment: This should be closed as a **simple typographical error**

Comment: wow, i didn't even to think to check the define, thank you.

Comment: now the only warning im getting during compilation is "implicit declaration of function exit" and "incompatible implicit declaration to built in function exit". i've used exit commands before in programs, and after referring back to those programs i see nothing wrong with my exit.

Comment: This isnt jut a simple typographical error. This is a fairly large program for me, and just getting the data into structure arrays is only the beginning. I'm here to acquire help and to also learn as being helped. I'm not asking for somebody else to write my code, i'm researching, attempting to write, and when that fails i will post here to see if anybody is willing to help me.

Comment: i updated my original post with what i'm encountering now. it's printing something hellish. i feel like the way i have it written is only for if the list was one student... i think? but i can't pinpoint where this would be handled.

Comment: i understand all of that, except for the ':'s' next to the %d... what is that?

Comment: also, i did that^, @user3121023, but the program crashed as soon as i tried to open the file, though no compile errors.

Answer (score 1):

STUDENT is a type. You cannot fgets into a type. There is no array STUDENT. Try this;

```
typedef struct aStudent
{
    char name[26];
    int id[7];
    int test1[4];
    int test2[4];
    int proj1[4];
    int proj2[4];
    int proj3[4];
    int ave[4];
    char grade[4];
} aStudent;
```

and;

```
 aStudent studentArray[MAX_STUDENTS];
```

and replace gGets with fscanf.

Comment: I thought i created a structure INSIDE array student at the end of my structure when i say }STUDENT[MAX_STUDENTS];

Comment: I think that what you have is an array type.   You declare 'STUDENT students;' and you get an array[45].... ?

Comment: @MartinJames would you mind elaborating on this more, please? What do you mean get an array[45]?

Comment: Ask john - I'm just guessing that you can use typedef to define an array type, eg.  STUDENT is an array of 45 structs.  I think.  Maybe.   Someone correct me if I'm wrong.  I've never used typedef like that, I've only typedeffed single structs and, if I need an array, I do it with the var declaration, eg:  'myType myVars[45];'

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have your struct set up incorrectly to handle the data you want to read from your file. Your data was:

```
name:score1:score2:score3:score5:lettergrade
```

A struct that makes sense (given the multiple scores) would be:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[MAXNM];
    int id;
    int scores[NGRDS];
    float ave;
    char grade;
} student;
```

(you have never accounted for where the `id` comes from and I'll leave it to use to split `name` into `first`, `last`, as your original question specified `name` and your recent edits added `first`, `last`)

What is clear is you want to read your datafile into a `struct` and compute the `ave` (average) from the grades read (which should be a floating-point type instead of `int`). Given your file format, reading each line of data with the `scanf` family functions is probably a bit more sensible than reading/tokenizing each line with `fgets/strtok`.

Your mixing of `fgets` and `fscanf` syntax will not work and exemplifies the difficulty in trying to shoehorn mixed data into a `scanf` type format string. You must take care in crafting the string to handle whitepace and any trailing newlines left in the input buffer. For your set of data, the following will work as well as anything else:

```
char *fmt = " %[^:]:%d:%d:%d:%d:%c";
```

Another way to account for the trailing newline is to use the *assignment suppression operator* to read and discard the trailing newline. When used, the discarded conversion is not added to the returned *match count*. e.g.

```
char *fmt = "%[^:]:%d:%d:%d:%d:%c%*c";
```

There is no need for macros to flush the input buffer if you craft your format string correctly.

Putting the pieces together, and leaving your belated change from `name` to `last`, `first` to you, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* constants for:
        NGRDS  - max number of grades per student.
        MAXNM  - max length of student name.
        MAXSTD - max number of students in array.
        MAXFN  - max filename length.
*/
enum { NGRDS = 4, MAXNM = 26, MAXSTD = 45, MAXFN = 128 };

typedef struct {
    char name[MAXNM];
    int id;
    int scores[NGRDS];
    float ave;
    char grade;
} student;

int main (void) {

    char filename[MAXFN];   /* initialize variables */
    char *fmt = " %[^:]:%d:%d:%d:%d:%c";
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    size_t i = 0, nstudents = 0;
    student students[MAXSTD] = {{ {""}, 0, {0}, 0.0, 0 }};

    printf ("\nEnter File Name:  ");
    if (scanf("%s", filename) != 1) {   /* validate filename read */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid file name entered.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fp = fopen (filename, "r"))) {    /* validate file open */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n.", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line in file */
    while (fscanf (fp, fmt, students[i].name, &students[i].scores[0],
                    &students[i].scores[1],&students[i].scores[2],
                    &students[i].scores[3], &students[i].grade) == 6) {
        int j;  /* compute sum/average */
        for (j = 0; j < NGRDS; j++) students[i].ave += students[i].scores[j];
        students[i].ave /= (float)NGRDS;
        if (++i == MAXSTD) {    /* check against max */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: students array full.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose (fp);    /* close file */
    nstudents = i;  /* save number of students */

    for (i = 0; i < nstudents; i++) {   /* output student data */
        size_t j;
        printf ("\n Student[%2zu]\n  name   : %s\n  scores :", 
                i, students[i].name);
        for (j = 0; j < NGRDS; j++) printf (" %d", students[i].scores[j]);
        printf ("\n  average: %.2f\n  grade  : %c\n", 
                students[i].ave, students[i].grade);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Data**

```
$cat dat/studentgrades.txt
Joe Cool:80:77:63:88:c
Nancy Smart:96:93:97:99:a
Dwane Dumb:61:60:67:50:f
Al Smith:75:77:78:73:c
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/studentstruct

Enter File Name:  dat/studentgrades.txt

 Student[ 0]
  name   : Joe Cool
  scores : 80 77 63 88
  average: 77.00
  grade  : c

 Student[ 1]
  name   : Nancy Smart
  scores : 96 93 97 99
  average: 96.25
  grade  : a

 Student[ 2]
  name   : Dwane Dumb
  scores : 61 60 67 50
  average: 59.50
  grade  : f

 Student[ 3]
  name   : Al Smith
  scores : 75 77 78 73
  average: 75.75
  grade  : c
```

(note: your letter grade should be computed based on the average, not simply read from the file -- what if the grades change? Also note that your input file format is fixed and inflexible. If the number of fields or their format changes in any way, you must account for the change in your `fmt` format string.)

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: im currently in another class now, when i get home later i really hope you're available to answer questions! like i said, i need to write this code, but i want to actually know what i'm doing as well. copying codes is how students make poor test grades.

Comment: I'll be around. I've got depo prep for tomorrow, so I'll welcome a break.

Comment: alright, so i basically pulled the code you provided me apart and i understand the majority of this... a lot more than i anticipated actually. thank you for labeling a lot of the code.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you are going to learn C, the whole trick involved is to *slow down*. Understand what each character on each line is for, look up each function in the *man pages*, understand its parameters **and** return, There are no tricks. With C you are responsible for managing ALL memory you allocate. (that is why C generally loads and executes 4X faster than Java or C++, only the resource necessary for your code are allocated and there is no huge class structure behind it checking everything you do) It's an exacting way of thinking, but with great benefits.